# Function not implemented

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I tried to authenticate the server with user name and password with the below url, there was error prompted in the server console.

```
http://servername/names.nsf?login&Username=Shibu%20Mathew&Password=welcome2lotus
```

HTTP Web Server: Function Not Implemented Exception

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: To the closer, I suspect you'll find that the configuration of the Notes web server is every bit as programming-related as Apache configuration :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably get this error because the server has been set up to use basic authentication (and not session-based authentication).

Try using `http://<username>:<password>@servername/` instead.

See more here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21176893